# Delphi: set Content-type of TCustomRestRequest on PUT

Tags: rest, delphi, put

I'm fighting a REST API call from Delphi. I want to send a PUT request to a server, with contenttype set to application/json:

```
    aCustomRestClient.BaseURL := domein;
    aCustomRestRequest.Client := aCustomRestClient;
    aCustomRestRequest.Response := aCustomRestResponse;
    aCustomRestRequest.Method := rmPUT;

    aCustomRestRequest.Resource := '/service/API/1501/allowanceCategory';
    aCustomRestRequest.Params.AddHeader('sessionId', SessionToken);

    qryAllowanceCategory.First;
    o := TJSONObject.Create;
    arr:=TJSONarray.create;

    try
      o.AddPair('createdBy',qryAllowanceCategory.fieldbyname('createdBy').AsString);
{lot more pairs here}
      o.AddPair('percentage', TJSONnumber.create(qryAllowanceCategory.fieldbyname('percentage').AsFloat));
      o.AddPair('remark',    'JUR '+ qryAllowanceCategory.fieldbyname('remark').AsString);
      arr.add(o);

      aCustomRestRequest.ClearBody;
      aCustomRestResponse.contenttype:='application/json';
      aCustomRestClient.contenttype:='application/json';
      aCustomRestRequest.AddBody(arr.ToString);

      aCustomRestRequest.Execute;
```

However, when I view my request as sent with Fiddler:

```
PUT http://shadow.jdvretail.com/service/API/1501/allowanceCategory HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,
Accept-Charset: utf-8, *;q=0.8
Authorization: Basic <<Authorization properly filled>>
User-Agent: Embarcadero RESTClient/1.0
sessionId: <<sessionID GUID properly filled here>>
Content-Length: 542
```

The Content-type remains wrong... how/where do I correctly set the contentType to 'application/json'?

Answer (score 1):

`TRestClient.AddBody(<string>)` has an optional second parameter allowing to set the content type.

```
procedure AddBody(const ABodyContent: string; AContentType: TRESTContentType = ctNone); overload;
```